# Проблема с запуском docker контейнера

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

Пытаюсь запустить контейнер из своего образа, но выдаёт ошибку доступа на 38 строке в файле docker-entrypoint.sh .

```
sudo docker run -it --name hw9_ivan2 -p 4000:8080 hw-l9:1
/docker-entrypoint.sh: 38: exec: hw9/result: Permission denied
```

Пытался найти файл docker-entrypoint.sh , чтобы увидеть эту 38 строку, но так его и не нашёл. Как это можно пофиксить?
Также прилагаю код Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.6 as build
ENV VAR=80
WORKDIR ./hw9
COPY hw9.py .
RUN python3 hw9.py -o result

FROM nginx:1.21.1
WORKDIR hw9/result
COPY --from=build ./hw9 ./hw9/result

CMD ["./hw9/result"]
```

Работаю в WSL Ubuntu под Windows

Comment: Не ясно чего вы хотите добиться. `CMD` - это параметр, который будет передан в ENTRYPOINT, для `ngingx:1.21.1` и соответственно вашего контейнера это `/docker-entrypoin.sh`. Он пробует выполнять этот файл командой exec (вы можете это увидеть выполнив `docker run -ti nginx:1.21.1 /bin/bash` и потом `cat /docker-entrypoin.sр`). `hw9/result` вообще является исполняемым? И вам точно нужно использовать entrypoint по умолчанию из nginx?

Comment: @RomanKonoval , спасибо большое, CMD и правда была лишней, из-за этого всё и началось!